# The size of the background image change

Tags: css, jsp, jstl

Hi all and thanks for your time.

I have a issue.

In a jsp i use a for to cycle on an array and the content is printed with a jstl for. When this array has a number of items (usually over 6). The background image begins to wrap and stretch, is there a way to avoid this so unpleasant effect?

I tried with a larger image but the effect is the same. I tried to modify a bit through CSS but I did not manage to get a solution, I hope to have explained to me well on what is the problem.

Comment: any sample codes or behaviour screenshot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if its a full page background try to add it in css file with using div

```
position:fixed
left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;
background:url();
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
```